# Remove admin rights

Tags: 2007

My bosses would like a site that the management can access and no one else...including the administrator.  How can I remove the administrator from full rights on a particular site?

Comment: I love this.  And what happens when the site goes haywire...

"I thought you IT guys could fix anything?"

"But Sir, you removed our access..."

"Just fix it...Yesterday!"

Answer (score 6):

Between the virtual machine servers, SQL servers, backup servers, SANs and front-end servers, there are a number of points where IT can access your data if they really want to. We've been through it over and over at my last job, there isn't a 100% secure way. Even Microsoft's own DPM backs-up SharePoint in full unprotected glory (DPM admins can browse/restore ALL archived data, regardless of permissions on the farm). What is stopping IT from taking a copy of the content database files straight from SQL and restoring it on a SP install on their laptop?

Hosted account === entrusting your data to 3rd party, how is that more secure? If your answer is along the lines of contracts and liability, you can have the same (or better) over your own employees.

Better go this way: Read up on Windows Domain, SQL and SharePoint security best practices, turn on appropriate Windows auditing, remove/disable anonymous admin accounts (aka "Administrator" and such) and make your high-security IT staff sign extra NDAs. Review your audit logs periodically. Encase everything in proper SOPs.

Your only protection is legal, unless management knows how to run their own isolated infrastructure.

Comment: I don't disagree.  I changed my answer to reflect what I meant to type before in my haste.  The fact is that if your site needs to be secure from internal resources, but the information is not sensitive enough that people outside the organization would care or if the information is cryptic to outsiders and collaborative, for example,  in nature, then a hosted solution would be viable.  I agree with your comment that it is a legal issue.  Our systems guy holds the keys to the kingdom -- he is both trusted and obligated to keep it private.  Every company should have such a person.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a separate site collection for them and make them the site collection administrators.  There is a way to allow the farm administrator to still be able to manage the farm settings and backups while removing his access to the site content.  See these articles for information:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262690.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263291.aspx

In reality, the farm admin and/or SQL Server admin may still be able to browse the content on the content databases I suppose.  It wouldn't be easy, but possible.  In a situation where they need to be secure from internal resources, maybe getting a hosted account just for management would be a good way to go -- depending on the nature of the content.

Comment: I have upvoted both comments posted so far here as I agree they're both viable options. Spend more and more on your governance plan, or keep your current one and entrust your data using a hosted solution like BPOS or similar from a third party provider.