# sharepoint with FBA, prevent site administrator from viewing content

Tags: security, wss-3.0

I would like to set up a site using FBA, where one requirement is that no one other than a few select people have access to data in the site.  That would mean that once the site is set up with FBA, not even the sharepoint administrator should be able to see the data in lists. 
Is this possible?

Comment: What is the requirement for removing an administrator access, that smells to me like a flaky (or non-existent) governance plan is in place.

Answer (score 1):

Joe.  There was actually a great discussion on that just recently.  The same concepts would apply as in the following thread:
[Remove admin rights](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4519/remove-admin-rights/4520#4520)

Answer (score 0):

This just might be possible.
If your Sharepoint administrator logs in via NTLM and the users with FBA.

In Central Administration you can go to the link *Policy for Web Application*
Once there you can add specific people to the website

By clicking *Add Users* you'll see a page where you can select the web application and the Zone. Select the FBA zone. 
After that you'll be able to select someone from the FBA users and assign roles to him/her.

After all is set up you can remove the Sharepoint Administrator from this list. Using this technique could probably work for your website.

Haven't tested it, but when I try to log in with the admin account on a FBA site and the administrator isn't assigned to the zone, I can't log in.